# Successfully Installed Java JDK 8, But Alternative JRE is Attempted to be Used

Tags: 14.04, apt, java, jdk

when I run `java -version`, I get this:

```
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

`$JAVA_HOME` is set to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` and whenever I try to remove or install a package using `apt-get`, I get this after the prompt to continue:

```
Setting up jre1.8.0-101 (1.8.0101-1) ...
Unpacking JAR files...
    plugin.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/plugin.pack
    javaws.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/javaws.pack
    deploy.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/deploy.pack
    rt.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/rt.pack
    jsse.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/jsse.pack
    charsets.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/charsets.pack
    localedata.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/ext/localedata.pack
update-alternatives: error: alternative ControlPanel can't be slave of java: it is a master alternative
dpkg: error processing package jre1.8.0-101 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jre1.8.0-101
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have both a Java JRE (located in the directory shown in the error) and JDK installed on my machine, and after doing some research that a JRE is a subset of a JDK, I realized I might not need that extra JRE. So is the JRE specified above needed? What to these errors mean?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.